# Using Kafka to migrate data from API to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, apache-kafka

I am new to Data Engeenering, and am picking up a project for personal growth.

I understand Kafka is used for data ingestion, but does it make sense to use it to ingest data from an API to AWS S3?

Is there another way to do the same, or what situation can be brought to use Kafka in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ingest streaming data to S3 is [Kinesis Data Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/). Kinesis is a technology similar to Kafka, and Data Firehose is its specialised version for delivering data to S3 (or other destinations). It's fairly cheap and configurable, and much, much less hassle than Kafka if all you want to do is get data onto S3. Kafka is great, but it's not going to deliver data to S3 out of the box.

Comment: So assuming that there are two aspects of this data retrieval, a historical dataset, and one-real time, what do you think is a good setup to get all the raw data into s3? Initially I was thinking more of getting historical with kafka, and real-time with Kafka+Spark

Comment: I know too little about what you're trying to do to answer that. If there's an API and you want data to S3 you need some process that will query the API, right? Couldn't that process also put the data on S3 directly? Is there really be a difference between historical and current data in an API? Perhaps you can describe your project in more detail (edit your question) to make it easier to write a more detailed answer?